# Woocommerce + Financity problems

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

so basically I'm at a dead end. The problem I have has to do with the WordPress plugin Woocommerce and how it is implemented on my site.

First of all, my site is completely in Estonian, so I'm using Loco Translate and Polyland to actively translate strings. But some of the strings do not change. An example of this would be [this](https://proscreen.eu/hydraport/), where the product has correct "Add to Cart" button translation, but "View details" has not changed.

Secondly, the text box padding or layout is kind of broken, as seen [here](https://proscreen.eu/pood/kat-esitlustehnika/kat-juhtmega/amx-hydraport/). The configuration text should span across the page and the attributes' drop-down menu should be below it.

If anyone has any solutions to those problems, please do let me know.

Sincerely,
Arthur

Comment: ¿Have you tried asking the support on Loco Translate plugin or Polyland? It seems there is some kind of conflict.

Comment: @Syntax_Error I have tried creating a new site which used a different theme but same plugins, but the problem still persisted. If I could find the .php file which contains that piece of text I could change it manually, but that's also nowhere to be found

Comment: OK the first problem was solved by `add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) { 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Text to translate', 'Translation', $translated); 
    return $translated; 
}`